# How Can I write this notation?

Tags: notation

Is this notation correct?

$$x^n \iff\begin{cases} x^{2n-1} \\ x^{2n}\end{cases}$$

Here $x,n \in \mathbb{N}$

**I'm trying to say**

Cluster $x^{2n} ∪ x^{2n-1}= x^n$

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean exactly? What should $x=2x-1$ mean?

Comment: Is that supposed to read _7^x if and only if { whatever the right hand side means_? If not, perhaps you could say _in words_ what you want it to communicate.

Comment: How can $x$ assume multiple values simultaneously?

Comment: @Hirshy I fixed now

Comment: You should use "if $x=2k$" and "if $x=2k-1$" to avoid having $x$ on both sides of $=$.

Comment: This didn't fix anything, what do you mean by "If $x=2x-1$"? If $x=2x-1$, then you have $x=1$. If $x=2x$ then you have $x=0$.

Comment: I want to use equivalent symbol, or other symbols.. :(

Comment: As Useless said before, you should explain what you are trying to say, then we can help you with what the symbols should be.  We still don't understand what you are trying to say.  Changing the $7$ to $n$ didn't change anything.  One problem is the $x$ on both sides of the (funny) equals sign.  That is close to computer usage of assignment (but I have usually seen := for that).  Using the equivalent symbol should not be the point, communicating your idea should be the point.

Comment: Regarding your latest edit: no, this notation is not correct. And it would be really good if you followed the advice by Ross Millikan. Talk to us, explain what you are trying to accomplish instead of using some weird symbols.

Comment: @Hirshy I try say Cluster $x^{2n} ∪ x^{2n-1}= x^n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the "cluster" comments, what I believe you may be referring to is this:

$$\{\color{red}{x^1},\color{blue}{x^2},\color{red}{x^3},\color{blue}{x^4},\color{red}{x^5},\color{blue}{x^6},\dots\}=\{\color{red}{x^1},\color{red}{x^3},\color{red}{x^5},\dots\}\cup \{\color{blue}{x^2},\color{blue}{x^4},\color{blue}{x^6},\dots\}$$

I would write this as:

$\{x^n~:~n\in\Bbb N\}=\{x^{2n}~:~n\in\Bbb N\}\cup \{x^{2n-1}~:~n\in\Bbb N\}$ assuming that you treat $\Bbb N=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ where $0$ is not considered a natural number.

If you do treat $0$ as a natural number, the above can be modified easily enough.

Answer (score 2):

Your notation is very unclear. I suspect you are trying to distinguish whether $x$ is an even or odd integer. In that case, you probably mean

$$y=\begin{cases} 7^{(x+1)/2},& \textrm{if } x = 2n-1 \textrm{ for some } n\in\mathbb Z   \\ 7^{x/2},& \textrm{if } x = 2n \textrm{ for some } n\in\mathbb Z   
\end{cases}$$

This makes $y=7^n$ for the $n$ that "works" for $x$.

That's because if $x=2n-1$, then $n=(x+1)/2$, and if $x=2n$, then $n=x/2$.

Is that what you intend?

Note that you could write this even more compactly as
$$y=7^{\lfloor (x+1)/2 \rfloor}$$
where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the greatest integer function. This only works if $x$ is an integer, which I suspect is the case you are considering.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the nonsensical nature of my original answer, and for interpreting this question in the way you did, +1 on my end

Comment: I think the real mistake is using "$x$" on both sides. Note that I used "$x$" and "$n$". They really are different.

Comment: I try to say , are they equal? I can not find symbol

Comment: No, your notation isn't meaningful

Comment: The symbol "$\iff$" is used to claim that two statements are equivalent. "$x^n$" is not a statement, it is an expression (a value). The other side is meaningless since there are no conditions on the piecewise cases.

Comment: I try say Cluster $x^{2n} ∪ x^{2n-1}= x^n$